# dotNetty proxy - wait for response before continuing

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, netty, dotnetty

I have written a TCP-proxy using dotNetty, and so far it's working great! But now I am having a problem with waiting for the response from the server that the proxy is connecting to.

The server accepts client connections, and in the ChannelActive-method of the primary handler, I am creating a second channel that connects to another server. I can then send messages from the client to the second server and also listen for messages form the second server to the client and translate those messages. There is a certain message from the client, that requires some information from the server to correctly translate the message.

So in the ChannelRead-method of the primary handler I'm checking the message-type and sending the required message-type to gather the information needed. I would simply store that information as a channel-attribute. But how can I guarantee that a response from the server has been processed before sending the next message?

I have marked the place where I want the outboundChannel to wait for a response before continuing with the next message in the following snippet:

```
internal class SapChannelInboundHandler : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ISapTelegram>
{

    private IChannel outboundChannel;

    public override async void ChannelActive(IChannelHandlerContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SapChannelInboundHandler - Channel active");

        context.Channel.GetAttribute(SfsServer.SapTelegramsToAcknowledge).Set(new List<ISapTelegram>());

        var inboundChannel = context.Channel;

        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.Group(inboundChannel.EventLoop);

        if (ServerSettings.UseLibuv)
        {
            bootstrap.Channel<TcpChannel>();
        }
        else
        {
            bootstrap.Channel<TcpSocketChannel>();
        }

        bootstrap.Option(ChannelOption.AutoRead, true); // <-- important!
        bootstrap.Handler(new MesChannelInitializer(inboundChannel));

        outboundChannel = await bootstrap.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1",8015);
        

    }


    protected async override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, ISapTelegram msg)
    {

        List<ISapTelegram> openTelegrams = ctx.Channel.GetAttribute(SfsServer.SapTelegramsToAcknowledge).Get();
        if (msg.Header.Handshake != "AK")
        {
            openTelegrams.Add(msg);
        }


        if(msg.Header.TelegramType == SapTelegramType.DS)
        {
            var symbolicPointInformationRequest = new MesGetProductionAreaInformationTelegram();
            symbolicPointInformationRequest.InfoType = 3;

            await outboundChannel.WriteAndFlushAsync(symbolicPointInformationRequest);

            // <--------------------- I need to make sure that a response has beenreceived and processed before continuing here

        }
        

        if (outboundChannel.Active)
        {
            await outboundChannel.WriteAndFlushAsync(msg);
        }

    }

    public override void ChannelReadComplete(IChannelHandlerContext context) => context.Flush();

    public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SapChannelInboundHandler - Exception: " + exception);
        context.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to wait for a response? Or can I set a bool ChannelAttribute if a response has been received and then make the thread sleep (maybe 10 ms) until the the attribute is set? Thanks!